# 'La ruta de acceso de archivo dada termina con un carácter separador de directorio

Tags: c#

Tengo este error

> La ruta de acceso de archivo dada termina con un carácter separador de
> directorio.

cuando intento eliminar un archivo. Es en C# con Visual Studio.

```
nombre = path.getfilenamewithoutextension(nombre de archivo seleccionado con openfiledialog)
ext = path.getextension(archivo seleccionado con openfiledialog)
...
computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(form1.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/" + form1.nombre + form1.ext);
```

Comment: Seria recomendable que editaras la pregunta y colocaras todo el código del procedimiento donde obtienes la ruta `form1.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` y además la referencia de donde provienen las variables `form1.nombre` y  form1.ext``, en tu pregunta y en la repuesta de Pablo Gutiérrez todavía quedan muchas dudas que puede que provoquen que no funcione bien, a prueba de errores.

Comment: Bro, fijate que si lo puse, deberías leer.

Comment: En tu pregunta hay una linea de código y dos lineas de pseudocódigo, ninguna está dentro de un bloque de procedimiento o función, el resto del código está omitido, es a eso a lo que me refiero; pero asumiendo lo que se puede inferir de tu pregunta, he colocado una respuesta que espero que te pueda ser util.

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que el separador de directorios es diferente según el sistema operativo, utilizar `/` no funciona en windows.

Cuando se trata de construir rutas de acceso a archivos, lo más recomendable es utilizar el método [`System.IO.Path.Combine(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.Combine);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1).

Este método garantiza que la ruta sea construida adecuadamente sin importar el sistema operativo.

Así tu ejemplo lo puedes escribir de la siguiente manera (*se asume que* `form1.ext` *contiene el `.`*):

```
Path.Combine(form1.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, form1.nombre + form1.ext)
```

Vale destacar la existencia de `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` que contiene el separador de directorios específico del sistema operativo.

En otro orden de ideas, dejo algunas referencias que te pueden interesar:

[interpolación de string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) para mejorar la escritura del código cuando se trata de concatenar string.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, te cuento luego como me fue.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una linea de código `computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(form1.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/" + form1.nombre + form1.ext);`, en donde se nota que has obtenido la ruta a una carpeta desde la propiedad `SelectedPath` de un `FolderBrowserDialog`, pero introduces dos variables `form1.nombre + form1.ext`cuyo origen parece provenir de las dos siguientes lineas que no son código, si no pseudocódigo.

nombre = path.getfilenamewithoutextension(nombre de archivo seleccionado con openfiledialog)

ext = path.getextension(archivo seleccionado con openfiledialog)

De ambas lineas se puede inferir que `nombre` y `ext` se obtienen a partir de un `OpenFileDialog`, si eso as así, no veo la necesidad de usar `FolderBrowserDialog`, seria suficiente con usar la propiedad `FileName` del `OpenFileDialog`
Con este código que te dejo a continuacion seria más que suficiente.

```
OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openfiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   if( System.IO.File.Exists(openfiledialog.FileName))
   {
       System.IO.File.Delete(openfiledialog.FileName);
   }
}
```

Comment: No me sirve, gracias igualmente.

Comment: @MartinoGarcia. En la forma que planteas tu pregunta es muy difícil poder ayudarte, como ya expliqué omites parte del código; no queda claro en tu pregunta, por que obtienes la ruta a la carpeta con un `FolderBrowserDialog`y el nombre y la extensión del archivo lo obtienes `OpenFileDialog`cuando este ultimo te da toda esa información  en una sola cadena, la ruta o `Path`del archivo. Si tu pregunta es incompleta, si no das todos lo detalles del problema a que te enfrentas y ante una respuesta que no te satisface solo contestas "No me sirve" hay muy pocas posibilidades de ayudarte.

Comment: No me sirve, gracias igualmente.

Comment: Hola, yo uso un folderbrowserdialog, porque como lo dice su nombre quiero buscar una carpeta.

Comment: @MartinoGarcia Pero el archivo, parece que lo buscas con `OpenFileDialog`, si eso es así ya tienes la carpeta donde está ubicado el archivo, solo puedo asegurarte que si usas `FolderBrowserDialog`  y  `OpenFileDialog`, uno de los dos es innecesario.

Comment: No, lo que estoy haciendo es copiar un archivo por eso el openfiledialog y pegarlo en na carpeta, por eso el folderbrowserdialog. ¿A ver cual es innecesario?

Comment: @MartinoGarcia Volvemos al mismo punto, en que te dije, que tu pregunta no da todos los elementos para poder ayudarte, pues si  "lo que estoy haciendo es copiar un archivo por eso el openfiledialog y pegarlo en una carpeta , por eso el folderbrowserdialog", eso no se ve por ninguna parte en tu pregunta; en tu pregunta lo único que se puede deducir es que en una carpeta obtenida con un `FolderBrowserDialog` estas intentando eliminar un archivo cuyo nombre y extensión la obtienes  de un `OpenFileDialog` que aparece en pseudocódigo; copiar un archivo y pegarlo, no está presente en tu pregunta.

Comment: Capo, si no sabes ya está no importa, pero estás cuestionando mi proyecto diciendo cosas que no son así.

Comment: @MartinoGarcia Disculpa amigo, solo he tratado de ayudar, no he cuestionado tu proyecto, pues ni siquiera conozco lo más mínimo sobre el; he cuestionado tu pregunta, por que entiendo que no daba todos los elementos para poder ayudarte, pues en definitiva, para ayudarnos es que estamos en este foro.